# Powershell to Copy files from one server to another and rename using substring

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

and thank you in advance!!! I was able to successfully move documents from one server(sharepoint) to another (pulse). However, each document begins with HC_.jpg. 
How can I move the document and rename at the same time. Currently I am using two separate scripts and two separate scheduled tasks which is less than ideal.

**First Script that moves the document from SharePoint Server:**

```
######################## Start Variables ########################
######################## Adam's Script######################
$destination = "\\pulse-dev.domain.com\C$\ProfilePhotos\"
$webUrl = "http://mysites-dev.domain.com"
$listUrl = "http://mysites-dev.domain.com/user photos/"
##############################################################

$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $webUrl
$list = $web.GetList($listUrl)

function ProcessFolder {
param($folderUrl)
$folder = $web.GetFolder($folderUrl)
foreach ($file in $folder.Files) {
#Ensure destination directory
$destinationfolder = $destination + "/" + $folder.Url 
if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))
{
$dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory 
}
#Download file
$binary = $file.OpenBinary()
$stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" + $file.Name), Create
$writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
$writer.write($binary)
$writer.Close()
}
}

#Download root files
ProcessFolder($list.RootFolder.Url)
#Download files in folders
#foreach ($folder in $list.Folders)   {

#ProcessFolder($folder.URL)
#}
```

**Second Script that is run on the Pulse server after first script completes**

```
$dir= "C:\ProfilePhotos\"
CD $dir
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
where-Object {$_.Name -match 'HC_'} |

Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'HC_', ''}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
$stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" + $file.Name), Create
```

with

```
$stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" + ($file.Name -replace "^HC_")), Create
```

Comment: Thank you for helping this newb, very much appreciated!